# Location for pop up activity

Tags: android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an activity that I want to show as popup window.

I have the following code, but the activity is shown in the center. I would like to show it in a different location. Possibly under my toolbar.

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup_message);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = 120;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .98), height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get current view window and set x and y params of that window. So it will get set on desired place.

Following is the example of how i have set my dialog on desire place.

```
    Window window = getWindow();
    // set "origin" to top left corner, so to speak
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START);
    // after that, setting values for x and y works "naturally"
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.x =selectedViewWidth;
    params.y = selectedViewHeight/2;

    window.setAttributes(params);
```

> I personally think that if you want to show popup window then instead of using activity you can also use `PopupWindow` or `DialogFragment`. You can manage by this controls more effectively.
>   There are so many tutorials available for same.

Comment: Thank you! I added the code as you wrote but I have an issue with getDialog(). Is it something I need to define somewhere else?

Comment: Use `Window window = getWindow()`;   getDialog() was my code to get current window. As you are in activity you can directly use `getWindow()` instead.